# Debug iNetMgr.exe unhandle exception System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException

Tags: windows, powershell, debugging, iis-7

I fired up my Windows 7 machine today and attempting to start Intemgr.exe the process terminates immediately. So I started the process under the debugger. It seems the process is terminating with the following exception: **System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException**. Dumping all exceptions on the heap yields the following results. The heap also has a few more exception listed below.

So based on my research this exception happens when a cmdlet encounters a terminating error. The method call just before is ProcessRecord(). Which Provides a record-by-record processing functionality for the cmdlet. The Windows PowerShell runtime calls this method multiple times for each instance of the cmdlet in the pipeline.

How can I inspect the pipeline from the debugger?

```
Exception object: 0000000002702940
Exception type: System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException
Message: Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ApplicationServer\ApplicationServer.dll' because it does not exist.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000001FF5E2C0 000007FEE1348846 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ExpandMshGlobPath(System.String, Boolean, System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo, System.Management.Automation.Provider.ContainerCmdletProvider, System.Management.Automation.CmdletProviderContext)+0xdb6
    000000001FF5E440 000007FEE1346162 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ResolveDriveQualifiedPath(System.String, System.Management.Automation.CmdletProviderContext, Boolean, System.Management.Automation.Provider.CmdletProvider ByRef)+0x442
    000000001FF5E540 000007FEE1345888 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedMonadPathsFromMonadPath(System.String, Boolean, System.Management.Automation.CmdletProviderContext, System.Management.Automation.Provider.CmdletProvider ByRef)+0x228
    000000001FF5E610 000007FEE134970A System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedProviderPathsFromMonadPath(System.String, Boolean, System.Management.Automation.CmdletProviderContext, System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo ByRef, System.Management.Automation.Provider.CmdletProvider ByRef)+0x22a
    000000001FF5E6D0 000007FEE136C33D System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedProviderPathsFromMonadPath(System.String, Boolean, System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo ByRef, System.Management.Automation.Provider.CmdletProvider ByRef)+0x7d
    000000001FF5E740 000007FEE17FC95C System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.PathIntrinsics.GetResolvedProviderPathFromPSPath(System.String, System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo ByRef)+0x7c
    000000001FF5E7C0 000007FEE18BF50B System_Management_Automation_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.GetResolvedPath(System.String, System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext)+0x6b

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131501
****************************************************************************************
Exception object: 0000000002715c50
Exception type: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Message: The specified module 'ApplicationServer' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
<none>
StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80070002
****************************************************************************************
Exception object: 00000000027bc4d0
Exception type: System.NotImplementedException
Message: The method or operation is not implemented.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000001FF5E0A0 000007FF001D3D08 Microsoft_ApplicationServer_Management_Tools!Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Management.Tools.PowershellHost.NoConsolePSRawUserInterface.get_BufferSize()+0x28
    000000001FF5E0D0 000007FEE12EC281 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostRawUserInterface.get_BufferSize()+0x61
    000000001FF5E130 000007FEDF893FAA Microsoft_PowerShell_Commands_Utility_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ConsoleLineOutput.get_ColumnNumber()+0x8a
    000000001FF5E1A0 000007FEDF893D04 Microsoft_PowerShell_Commands_Utility_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessOutOfBandPayload(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData)+0xc4
    000000001FF5E210 000007FEDF893BC4 Microsoft_PowerShell_Commands_Utility_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessPayload(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData, OutputContext)+0xe4
    000000001FF5E280 000007FEDF897110 Microsoft_PowerShell_Commands_Utility_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessObject(System.Management.Automation.PSObject)+0x1a0
    000000001FF5E300 000007FEDF89238B Microsoft_PowerShell_Commands_Utility_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.OutCommandInner.ProcessRecord()+0xdb
    000000001FF5E360 000007FEDF896AAE Microsoft_PowerShell_Commands_Utility_ni!Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FrontEndCommandBase.ProcessRecord()+0x3e
    000000001FF5E3B0 000007FEE13726F2 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()+0x212

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80004001
****************************************************************************************
Exception object: 00000000027bc770
Exception type: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException
Message: The method or operation is not implemented.
InnerException: System.NotImplementedException, use !PrintException 00000000027bc4d0 to see more
StackTrace (generated):
<none>
StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131501
****************************************************************************************
Exception object: 00000000027bcbd8
Exception type: System.Management.Automation.PipelineStoppedException
Message: The pipeline has been stopped.
InnerException: <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000001FF5E3B0 000007FEE1ACB9B8 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()+0x7594d8
    000000001FF5E450 000007FEE1357B44 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()+0x84
    000000001FF5E4C0 000007FEE13879C9 System_Management_Automation_ni!System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoStepItems(System.Object, System.Collections.Hashtable, Boolean)+0x79

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80131501
```

Comment: What is the powershell command?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question here.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d445c21-22ee-45ee-80fe-1d39a3b40304/appfabric-crashes-iis-manager-when-powershell-4-is-installed-server-2008-r2-sp1?forum=velocity

Uninstall App-Fabric.